# How do I create my own group on facebook by android app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I have read this page(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups) and I can get all my groups, but it can create new group according the webpage. How can I create my group ( not app group ) like official website and app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create "normal" groups via the facebook website, and not via the Graph API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group#publish

> You can't publish on this endpoint.